# Saving pdf from print content HTML JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, printing

If you print a page it gives you chance to download as pdf, can I make somehow automatically a button when i click it to open print and download as PDF

Comment: The option to save as a PDF when printing is provided by the user's browser/OS rather than being a native component of HTML/JS, so you cannot manipulate it. However, there are tools such as [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to let you generate your own PDFs.

Comment: Yes I use fpdf render to make render but for that I need to reprocess things so it's kind of ready just to take the div content. Thanks @oxguy3

Comment: Short answer is no, you can't control a print dialog other than opening it. The reasons why should be obvious...do you want random websites controlling your printer and forcing downloads?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Save as PDF is part of your OS/Environment and depends from what APP you have installed (some are native, some are not).

Javascript of your webpage cannot request or access to resource that cannot be available on your OS/Environment, can only access to your browser functions.

Your **OS** execute the **browser APP** that execute **javascript script** on your **webpage**.

**Browser** can access to **printers** but **javascript** cannot (mainly because it's designed to be like this).